# Excel VBA How to match WorkSheet name with Cell value, then Copy and Paste a Range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am just trying to copy and paste from value from one workbook to another, when the top cell of the "Target" workbook is matching the Worksheet's name.

But it is giving me error 1004 for most of the time. Any ideas?

```
Sub Cycle()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim y As Integer

 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Target").Cells(1, y)
            Worksheets("Target").Range(Cells(2, y), Cells(24, y)).Copy
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range("e3").Paste
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

            y = y + 1


        Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel does not have a column 0, so `Cells(1, y)` won't work when `y` is 0.  (Initialise `y` to 1 and it possibly won't crash - but I don't think your code is doing what you think it is going to do.)

Comment: Right, it's not working at work, it only does copy and paste the value into the same Target sheet but I actually want the values in different columns of the target sheet to be copied into multiple worksheets

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand exactly what you want, but give this a try:

```
Sub Cycle()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsTarg As Worksheet: Set wsTarg = Worksheets("Target")
Dim y As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    y = 1
    While (wsTarg.Cells(1, y) <> vbNullString)
        If ws.Name = wsTarg.Cells(1, y) Then
            wsTarg.Range(wsTarg.Cells(3, y), wsTarg.Cells(25, y)).Value = _
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(23, 1)).Value
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Wend
Next ws
End Sub
```

It is not the best way to do that (we could optimize to avoid verifying columns that were already copied and do not verify the target spreadsheet), but it will look for all your Worksheets and compare with all the Cells on the first line on Target sheet. If the name of the sheet were exactly the same as the Cell name, it will copy the first column (cells 1 to 23) into the target sheet, on the cells 3 to 25.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Dear Bruno, thanks for the speedy reply. The copied cells is not pasting in the worksheet though. The cells just got copied and pasted in the same "Target" sheet. I do have around 50 sheets in the same file excel file with the "Target" sheet at the end. Would you mind telling me how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, now I understood. You want to do exactly the oposite. Copy from the"Target" sheet TO the others sheets!

So it is just to invert this line:

`ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(23, 1)).Value = wsTarg.Range(wsTarg.Cells(3, y), wsTarg.Cells(25, y)).Value`  As we inverted the process, maybe it would be a better idea to invert all the code. It would make it faster. Please, let me know if you need to do this in a big scale, so we can improve it. :)